# Saving the fig tree after a pruning session

Tags: pruning, figs

I've pruned my fig tree and I think I might have made some mistakes. I'd like to bring it down in size so that the fruit is reachable. Any advice (ideally with instructions) on what I can do to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Figs need heavy pruning to bear fruit on new wood. Mine tolerates pruning well. I would shorten some of the tallest branches that you left. Otherwise I see no problems. Remember, you get to prune again next winter. .

Comment: I was thinking of cutting the left branch completely in half to force it to grow lower side branches. I will not be able to reach the fruit on the left branches anyway as it's already too high.

Answer (score 2):

I used to work at an old house in Essex (UK) where there was a huge fig tree growing next to the front door. I've taken a chain saw to that tree, cut branches almost down to ground level and it still came back with a vengence, and bore loads of fruit. In short, figs are very forgiving trees. In fact, the problem with figs grown in the ground is that they can be too vigorous. With yours, I'd be tempted to cut those two remaining branches down to just above the height of the gravel board and then try to maintain it to no more than fence height. For general fig pruning advice see [here](https://realenglishfruit.co.uk/fig-tree-pruning-how-to-trim-a-fig-tree/).